# Procedure for selecting optimal number of features with Python's Scikit-Learn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-science-model

I have a dataset with 130 features (1000 rows) . I want to select the best features for my classifier. I started with `RFE` but Its taking too long, i done this:

```
number_of_columns = 130

for i in range(1, number_of_columns):
    rfe = RFE(model, i)
    fit = rfe.fit(x_train, y_train)
    acc = fit.score(x_test, y_test
```

Because this took to long, I changed my approach, and I want to see what you think about it, is it good / correct approach.

First I did `PCA`, and I found out that each column participates with around 1-0.4%, except last 9 columns. Last 9 columns participate with less than 0.00001% so I removed them. Now I have 121 features.

`pca = PCA()
fit = pca.fit(x)`

Then I split my data into train and test (with 121 features).

Then I used `SelectFromModel`, and I tested it with 4 different classifiers. Each classifier in `SelectFromModel` reduced the number of columns. I chosed the number of column that was determined by classifier that gave me the best accuracy:

```
model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
#train_score = clf.score(x_train, y_train)
test_score = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
column_res = model.transform(x_train).shape
```

End finally I used 'RFE'. I have used number of columns that i get with 'SelectFromModel'.

```
rfe = RFE(model, number_of_columns)
fit = rfe.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = fit.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Is this a good approach, or I did something wrong?

Also, If I got the biggest accuracy in `SelectFromModel` with one classifier, do I need to use the same classifier in `RFE`?

Comment: In your first code block, you probably shouldn't have a loop.  You ask to recursively eliminate down to just 1 feature, _then start over_ and recursively eliminate to just 2, and so on.  Just do the first one, and use the `ranking_` attribute.  Or, use `RFECV`.

Comment: PCA itself produces _new_ features that are linear combinations of the old ones, so directly doesn't give feature selection in the same sense.  But perhaps you are using it indirectly, as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27300/232706 ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try on Lasso (l1 penalty) which does automatic feature selection by „shrinking“ parameters. This is one of the standard approaches to data with many columns and „not so many“ rows.

```
sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty=’l1‘,...
```

See also [this post](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_path.html).

**Edit:**

The book „Introduction to Statistical Learning“ gives a really good overview. Here are the Python code examples from the book. [Section 6.6.2](https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python) covers the Lasso.

Comment: And can you tell me where to use lasso, I mean, what will my output be?
I have read the post that you posted, but I didnt make it to do it

Comment: output will be a classifier (you can predict on it, just as usual), but features are selected endogenously by the classifier.

Comment: Ok, but I read that I still need to specify the number of features, I want to write a code that will give the optimal number of features and what features

Comment: you can just dump all features and see what lasso does. This is the great advantage of lasso. You don‘t need to decide. It happens endogenously. You may have a look at Introduction to Statistical Learning, Chapter 6, really cool https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python

Comment: When I do `RFE`, and I get the columns/features that I should use, do I need to change my x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test (to make them only with columns that rfe selected) and run my classifier again, or not?

Answer (score 0):

For that amount of features I use Selectbest [sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)

To do this, I take 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4 of all the feaures and analyze how the score used to measure the error varies.

OTHER OPTION:

I use LassoCV
[sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html)

as follows:

```
kfold_on_rf = StratifiedKFold(
    n_splits=10, 
    shuffle=False, 
    random_state=SEED
)

lasso_cv = LassoCV(cv=kfold_on_rf, random_state=SEED, verbose=0)
sfm = SelectFromModel(lasso_cv)
```

Comment: What is SelectFromModel? Your answer says you use SelectKBest but that's not part of the code snippet?

Comment: I have tried with Lasso, and it gives me the worst score, less than 50%